# Same page on 2 different websites. Same SEO, but only 1 gets picked up by Google

Tags: seo, google-index

I made a page for a website (website A) I'm responsible for. I made sure the SEO is correct. This one got to position 1 in Google very fast. On the second website (website B) I copied exactly the same content and SEO. It is indexed by Google but it isn't showing in the results (I've waited 3-4 weeks before checking). Even when I scroll down the pages of results. It seems Google just don't want this site (website B) in its results!

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 5):

That is normal and expected behaviour and in SEO-terms that's called *Duplicate Content*. So Website A got indexed before Website B, and since the content is identical, Google sees no value in positioning Website B in its search results. There is no way around the issue than to rewrite Website B's content to be unique to get that website positioned in the SERP.

Read up on duplicate content [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359), [here](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/duplicate-content) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_content).

Comment: Haha, never thought of that... I'm going to rewrite website B and see what happens! Thx for your quick response.